# Google Column Chart Tooltip with ArrayToDataTable

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to show some texts for each series in a Google Bar Type chart.

The data I am using to create the chart is presented as below (perfectly working):

```
['Months', 'XXX', {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}, 'YYY', {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}, 'ZZZ', {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}, 'TTT', {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}], 
['Sep', 0, '00 h 00 m', 0, '00 h 00 m', 0, '00 h 00 m', 0, '00 h 00 m']
['Oct', 0, '00 h 00 m', 0, '00 h 00 m', 0, '00 h 00 m', 0, '00 h 00 m']
...
```

However, I can not manage to show the tooltip (or annotation, it doesn't matter).

I tried to load a lot of versions of Google packages. I currently use the following:

```
google.charts.load('visualization', '1',  {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {      
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ...
    ]);

    var options = {             
        height: 300,
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Flight Hours (min)'
        },
        title: 'Annual Statistics',                       
        bar: { groupWidth: '90%' },
    };


    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('myPieChart'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  }
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Material* charts do not support [Column Roles](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles)

in order to provide annotations or custom tooltips, you must use a *Classic* chart

---

*Material* = `google.charts.Bar` -- `packages: ['bar']`

*Classic* = `google.visualization.ColumnChart` -- `packages: ['corechart']`

---

there is an option for making *Classic* look **similar** to *Material*...

```
theme: 'material'
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Months', 'XXX', {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}, 'YYY', {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}, 'ZZZ', {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}, 'TTT', {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}],
    ['Sep', 5, '00 h 00 m', 6, '00 h 00 m', 7, '00 h 00 m', 8, '00 h 00 m'],
    ['Oct', 5, '00 h 00 m', 6, '00 h 00 m', 7, '00 h 00 m', 8, '00 h 00 m']
  ]);

  var options = {
    height: 300,
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Flight Hours (min)'
    },
    title: 'Annual Statistics',
    bar: {groupWidth: '90%'},
    theme: 'material'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**note:** `jsapi` should no longer be used to load the charts library,
according to the release notes...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. The last update, for security purposes, was with a pre-release of v45. Please use the new gstatic `loader.js` from now on.

this will only change the `load` statement, see above snippet...

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my time... I spent 4 hours just for trying to solve this problem. However, colors changed a little. I set up all my system according to Google Charts color list. Can I find the old one?

**EDIT:** I deleted the materials theme. It is OK now. Thank you again.